# JavaFx View component, WebView and MediaView Error

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

I'm not familiar with javaFX I just started.
I import the package and I did The VM option but when I try to add a WebView, ImageView or MediaView in the window I get this error causes

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class javafx.scene.media.NGMediaView (in unnamed module @0x18ebfb54) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.sg.prism to unnamed module @0x18ebfb54
```

All the other contents working fine, button, Slider, and so on
I don't know the problem where, I hope to help me guys Thank you

Comment: Did you add the import to `javafx.web` to your module/via command line parameter?

Comment: Thank you I think it's work now but when I create module-info.java I get this new error "java.lang.module.FindException: Module HelloJava not found"